# Bluetooth turn off if not connected to device

Tags: android, bluetooth, tasker

I'm using tasker and I want a profile that will turn my Bluetooth off if it is not connected to a device after a certain period of time

I have the following

```
Profile > Bluetooth off
State > Bluetooth On
State > Not BT Connected

Task > Bluetooth Off
A1 > Wait > 59s
A2 > popup
A3 > Bluetooth Off

Exit Task > Bluetooth Off
A1 > Bluetooth Off
```

The popup will appear and Bluetooth switches off but it is automatically coming straight back on

I'm on galaxy s3 rooted running JB 4.3

Comment: I just tried reproducing the problem, and when I put in `Bluetooth Off` into the Bluetooth Off task, I received a message saying:
"This is a *setting* action, indicated by the tools icon right in the action list.
It means that **when this profile is no longer active the value will be restored automatically**"
(bold added for emphasis). I'm not the most familiar with tasker, but could this potentially be the problem?

Comment: Hi @Aristocrates I'm the same, only started using it today, I've literally just tired it out again and it seems to be working now, I actually made a error in my post, I had the popup to display AFTER I switched the Bluetooth off, so I though what the hell lets try it the way it is in the post and it seems to have worked. 
Sorry there's not a more technical answer! If anyone does have more information on this though please reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and although Valiceemo's response is perfect to fix this problem the underlying issue could be that you have the "Restore Settings" option checked as a profile option.

If you click on the three dot menu and select preferences and deactivate "Beginners Mode" you can long press the profile and a new options menu will appear at the top with the slider menu icon, click on this and uncheck "Restore Settings". This should resolve the issue and let your original profile work.

Without knowing about this option Tasked can be seriously frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the profile I use for auto BT off.

```
Auto BT Off (72)
    A1: If [ %Bluetoothconn !~ 1 ]
    A2: Wait [ MS:0 Seconds:0 Minutes:5 Hours:0 Days:0 ] 
    A3: Bluetooth [ Set:Off ] 
    A4: End If
```

I have a profile set a variable %Bluetoothconn to 1 when connected. The exit task (i.e BT disconnected) clears this variable